# React re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning React and hit a roadblock.

CircularProgress is a component that loads a circle when the api is calling just in case anyone is wondering in the code below.

So basically, I have a state [stories, setStories] = useState([])

When the page loads, it calls an api and sets the stories and fills it up. It will render out all the information of each array and use that to create a component i called singlecard.

However, I have a button that updates the state and sorts it. This does work and it does change the state.

It will not re-render and I am unsure of how to change it.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

```
const [ stories, setStories ] = useState([]);
//some updater function

{loading ? <CircularProgress /> : (
   stories.map( (item,index) => {
   let i_title = item.title;
   let i_content = item.abstract;
   let i_url = item.url;
   let i_image = item.multimedia[0].url;
   return <Singlecard key={index} getimage={i_image} urlLink={i_url} headline={i_title} 
                  summary={i_content}/>
                    })
                )}
```

Comment: What do you mean the state is gone? Not really following your question here, does nothing render on screen when you click the button? Would be helpful if you could post your update function with your question as well :D

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant code you are working with as a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i am getting your problem , react should re render the jsx when there's state change. the problem might be in some other parts of the code? is it stuck in <CircularProhgress /> or previous stories state when stories state is updated?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to update the key of the component ‘Single card’ from index to an unique ID because React doesn’t know that the order of the items changed after it’s sorted so it stays the same.

```js
(item) => {
     let i_id = item.id
     let i_title = item.title;
     let i_content = item.abstract;
     let i_url = item.url;
     let i_image = item.multimedia[0].url;
     return <Singlecard key={i_id} getimage={i_image} urlLink=    {i_url} headline={i_title} summary={i_content}/>
      })
  )
```